# Assimp. Weird vertices coordinates after importing a model from Wavefront Obj file

Tags: c++, assimp

I've created a simple unit-sized plane in blender and exported it into .obj file which contents is this

```
# Blender v2.93.3 OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib plane.mtl
o Plane
v 1.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl None
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1 3/4/1
```

When I import it with assimp

```
unsigned flags = aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_OptimizeMeshes |
                     aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_SortByPType |
                     aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace /*|aiProcess_FlipWindingOrder*/;
const aiScene * scene = importer.ReadFile(path, flags);
for (int i = 0; i < scene->mNumMeshes; ++i)
    {
        const aiMesh * mesh = scene->mMeshes[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < mesh->mNumVertices; ++j)
        {
            const aiVector3D & vertex = mesh->mVertices[j];
            model->vertices.emplace_back(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
        // ...
```

it gives me weird results

```
x = {double} -0.007812501848093234
y = {double} -0.0078125
z = {double} 1.5873523201947252E-314

x = {double} 0.0078125055733835325
y = {double} 0.0078125
z = {double} 5.2635442471208903E-315

x = {double} 2.1053526862322168E-314
y = {double} -3.0421935264696467E-310
z = {double} 0

x = {double} 0
y = {double} 0
z = {double} 0
```

I expected values from 1 to -1 like they're in the .obj file
I also tried to pass 0 instead of flags, the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because i defined `ASSIMP_DOUBLE_PRECISION` and it was the cause